# Where i change header and footer links?

Tags: magento-1.9, url

When I change the **base url** in the Magento admin panel it doesn't work. I think it's hard coded somewhere but can't find this file.

Comment: after change admin url delete cache from var folder

Comment: we already tried that

Comment: check your root's index.php file. Also check the .htaccess files

Comment: I can't find it in those files

Comment: What do you want exactly? Change base url of your store? Or add remove links from header and footer?

Comment: I want to change the base url

Comment: Please accept the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow these three steps:

1. go to your admin panel and change your base url `System > Configuration > General > Web : Unsecure and Secure` then **clear your cache** and **reindex all**.
2. Find your current **header**, **footer**, etc.. with enabling a `Path hint`, if you don't know how please follow [this](http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints).
3. Atfer finding the current file `header.phtml` for exemple, you can now check if you have the **base url** hard coded or dynamically, the dynamic one looks like:

   - `$this->getBaseUrl()`
   - `Mage::getBaseUrl()`

Nb: Don't forget to clear the browser and Magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your database using PhpMyAdmin (or whichever database management software you're using) and open the `core_config_data` table. In here you need to find to replace the values of `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` with your new base URL.

After you've done this, clear `/var/cache/` and see if it then works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access you can also SSH into your web root and do

`$ grep -rl "https://myUrl.tld"`

which will print out all files containing the string `https://myUrl.tld`.

This might help to identify the files that contain the desired string.